# Angular 2 Router adds question mark to URL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my Angular 2 app I want to navigate to another URL using `this.router.navigate(['/todo']);`

It works but Angular adds a question mark after the URL (like this: `http://localhost:4200/todo?`) which makes the browser reload the page. However, I don't want the browser to refresh the page.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is it happening when you are trying to submit a form & redirecting somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, the buttons executing the code are being contained by a form element.

Comment: Seems related to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9936), try solution provided there

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thought that solution didn't worked for me, Glad to know that it worked for me, Thanks :-)